# How to process all the features of an annotation through JAVA Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, testng

I knew we can execute the class based on the annotation through java reflection.

The code will execute a methods which is annotated with `@Test`(TestNG framework). Is it possible to process the features which are available with that annotation?

If possible, How to implement the things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the annotation using `getAnnotation` instead of `isAnnotationPresent` (the former returns null if the annotation is not present), and then access its properties like any other Java object.

```
Test testAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
if (testAnnotation != null) {
  System.out.println(testAnnotation.priority());
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your inputs. I tried above code sample. I have 6 priorities in one class( class b) file when I executed the java reflection from class a file It executed the methods which is annotated and have property as priority but Its not executed the methods in order as its prioritized in class b. It executed priority 4 as first and followed by 3, 2,5,6,1 (Random execution)? Why its happening? is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: How are you sorting the methods by their priority? In other words, how are you implementing the semantics of `priority`?

Comment: My requirement is, I just need to invoke the method as per the priority value. Basically When do we execute the methods through testNG It will check the priority and let them execute in sequence order. But, here my case is that execution is taken care by reflection. I want to perform the same functionality which could be done by testNG through JAVA Reflection.That's why I questioned like how to enable the properties of @Test annotations. If its enabled then It has to take care of sequence execution. Pls correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: OK, so you need to implement the priority semantics: look for all methods with the annotation, put them in a container like a `TreeMap<Integer, Method>` (or a `List<Method>` and sort them explicitly), and then execute them in iteration order. Remember that the `priority` method may as well be called `foo`: there is nothing inherent about that name which imbues an order.

Comment: You're just awesome.. Thanks for great feedback, and input.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Method me : method) {
    Annotation[] annotations = me.getDeclaredAnnotations(); //get Annotations associated with that method

  for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
      if(annotation instanceof Test){
          Test myAnnotation = (Test) annotation;
          System.out.println("priority: " + myAnnotation.priority());
          System.out.println("dependsOnMethod: " + myAnnotation.dependsOnMethod());
      }
    }
}
```